# In jquery each Loop from json object How (make loop find a value from object and compare to another object value to not repeat a print)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Hi guys I am developing a music player and I'm using Json for store my ID3 or AKA "MP3 Metadata". The problem that I'm confronting is that I'm extracting an object and traingf to see if I can compare the value and if both object have the same value don't not repeat the print. In case I just want the artist one time not 2 to infinity repeat in

.

This is JSON File example;

```
[
{   
    "Artist": "",
    "Album": "",
    "Year":"",
    "Genre": "", 
    "Song": "",
    "Location": "",
    "Track": "",
    "Img": "",
    "Composer":""
},
    {   
    "Artist": "The Rolling Stones",
    "Album": "Hot Rocks (1964-1971)",
    "Year":"2002",
    "Genre": "Rock", 
    "Song": "Heart of Stone",
    "Location": "scr/music/TheRollingStones/HeartofStone.mp3",
    "Track": "2",
    "Img": "scr/music/TheRollingStones/img/HotRocks.jpg",
    "Record":"Sony Music"
},
    {   
    "Artist": "The Rolling Stones",
    "Album": "Hot Rocks (1964-1971)",
    "Year":"2002",
    "Genre": "Rock", 
    "Song": "Sympathy For The Devil",
    "Location": "scr/music/TheRollingStones/SympathyForTheDevil.mp3",
    "Track": "15",
    "Img": "scr/music/TheRollingStones/img/HotRocks.jpg",
    "Record":"Sony Music"
},

        {   
    "Artist": "Led Zeppelin",
    "Album": "The Complete Led Zeppelin",
    "Year":"2007",
    "Genre": "Rock", 
    "Song": "Good Times Bad Times",
    "Location": "scr/music/LedZeppelin/GoodTimesBadTimes.mp3",
    "Track": "1",
    "Img": "scr/music/LedZeppelin/img/The Complete Led Zeppelin.jpg",
    "Record":"Atlantic Records"
}

]
```

Javascript Document

```
    $.getJSON('scr/json/musicdata.json', function(data){
        var output = '<ol>';
             data.sort(function(a, b){
             return [a.Artist] < [b.Artist] ?  0 : 1;
         });//End of Sort by Artist 

         $.each(data, function(key,val) {

         if(val.Artist != ""){

         if(PreArtis != val.Artist){

        output += '<li><a class="songname" href="#" data-src="'+ val.Location +'">' + val.Artist + '</a></li>';
            var PreSong = val.Artist ;
         }//End of PreSong != Song
        }//End of val.Artist     
        });//End of Each 
         output += '</ol>';
        $("#wrapper").append(output);
        });//End of getJSON
```

Html

Thanks for you help in advances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var songs = {};
$.each(data, function(key,val) {
    if(val.Artist != ""){
        var key = val.Artist + '@' + val.Album;
        if(!songs[key]){
            output += '<li><a class="songname" href="#" data-src="'+ val.Location +'">' + val.Artist + '</a></li>';
            songs[key] = true ;
        }//End of PreSong != Song
    }//End of val.Artist     
});//End of Each 
output += '</ol>';
$("#wrapper").append(output);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MdCKX/)

You can change the `key` to find the unique combination. Ex: if you want a unique combination of Artist, Album and Song then use `var key = val.Artist + '@' + val.Album + val.Song`;